# Objective-C: NSArray of UISwitches

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, uiswitch

Ok so I;m building an interface to allow admins controlls over certain rules which are controlled using UISwitches (a lot of them)

so I've declared an array of switches

```
NSMutableArray *cameraSwitches = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
loc0CamProfileSwitch, loc1CamProfileSwitch, loc2CamProfileSwitch,
loc3CamProfileSwitch, loc4CamProfileSwitch, loc5CamProfileSwitch,
loc6CamProfileSwitch, loc7CamProfileSwitch, loc8CamProfileSwitch, nil];
```

where each object inside the Array is a UISwitch,

and then I'm looping through a diff array checking for initial values of these switches

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [camP count]; i++) {

    if ([camP objectAtIndex:i] != 0) {

        //UISwitch *csw = [cameraSwitches objectAtIndex:i];
        //[csw setOn:YES];

        [[cameraSwitches objectAtIndex:i] setOn:YES];
    else { [loc7CamProfileSwitch setOn:NO]; }
}
```

But everything I'm trying is giving me an error at runtime, throwing an exception 
`'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'`

using break points: I realize theres something wrong with this line

`[[cameraSwitches objectAtIndex:i] setOn:YES];` - or with how i initiated the array any help is very very appreciated

Comment: Your example is missing a closing brace before the else. It would help to see how campP is set up.

Comment: @Marco Pace well spotted! If that's nil, the array will have zero elements.

Comment: Thank guys, some help, I just did an NSLOG on CamP its fine (returning the right values) but my NSLOG on camera Switches is returning Nil ! - fixed the problem with the braces, the switches are declared in the header file, and defined right above the Array declaration as follows :
`[loc2CamProfileSwitch
 addTarget:self action:@selector(self)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cameraSwitches is correctly instantiated. that's why you get an exception raised when you try to reach index 0.

But, did you checked that loc0CamProfileSwitch (index 0) is non nil?

Comment: umm loc0CamProfileSiwtch is a refference to an actual UISwitch . . . . . :(

Comment: then NSLog your cameraSwitches, so that we can see what's inside. Try it after the initialization. (NSLog(@"%@", cameraSwitches))

Comment: the camera switches return null . . . . . (oh . oh )

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, `cameraSwitches` is getting deallocated after it's instantiated.  This could happen if you create it in a different method than when you're calling `objectAtIndex` and you're not setting it up as an iVar or @property (strong).

If that doesn't resolve the issue, put a breakpoint on `[[cameraSwitches objectAtIndex:i] setOn:YES]` and type `po cameraSwitches` in the debug console.